# Remove specific lines in a multiline textbox

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a Multiline textbox who I can paste URL's. The URL's will be paste into a string variable. Now I want, that just URL's from a specific domain can pass into the string variable.

**For example:**

```
http://domain-1.tld/gfdgfd.php?=2135346432
http://domain-2.tld/fsefes.php?=2145312542
http://domain-1.tld/random/folders/iwadaex.php?=2112313543
http://domain-2.tld/igewex.php?=2135464432
http://domain-1.tld/folder/inwadawx.php?=2135546432
http://domain-2.tld/ihtfhtf.php?=2143534432
```

I a have a radiobutton with `Domain 1` and `Domain 2`. If `Domain 1` is checked, Only URL's from `Domain 1` will be put in the variable, and so on.

I just need to know, how I filter the URL's...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result =  textBox1.Text.Split('\n').Where(x => x.Contains(@"http://" + domain)).ToArray();
```

**Edit after your comment :**

```
var str = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Comment: It works fine. But how can I convert this into a string variable?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Easy to understand :) i would upvote, but i need for reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

You can get your lines using `Lines` property then filter them using `Where` method:

```
var filteredUrls = textBoxName.Lines.Where(x => x.Contains(someValue)).ToArray();
```

Then if you want to display them together, you can use `String.Join`

```
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, filteredUrls);
```